# Multiple clicks on a button issue using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following html.I have implemented following jquery code but my delete button clicking two times.Basically one edit and one delete.When I click on edit only one click happens but when I click on delete , first delete button trigers then edit.How can I avoid this.please check my code.

```
$(".tools").live("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('clicked on edit');
    var n = $("a", this).attr('id');
    alert(n);
});

$(".tools").find('span').live("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('clicked on delete');
    var n = $("a", this).attr('id');
    alert(n);
});
```

```
<div class="tools">
    <a href="#" class="btn acebtn btn-minier btn-info" id="edit_'."$count".'">
        <i class="icon-only ace-icon fa fa-share"></i>
    </a>
    <span class="dlt">
        <a href="#" class="btn acebtn btn-minier btn-info dlt" id="delete_'."$count".'">
            <i class="icon-only ace-icon fa fa-share"></i>
            delete
        </a>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your click event on the span (delete button) is bubbling up and triggering the click event on the `.tools` element, which is your edit button.

You can prevent the event from bubbling up using [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/):

```
$(".tools").find('span').live("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('clicked on delete');
});
```

Side note: `.live()` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7, in favor of `.on()`.

Comment: Thanks I forgot to do  e.stopPropagation();

Comment: but how to use 'on' with 'find' instead of live

Comment: $("#ids").on("click", ".tools span", function(e){ }); some thing like this will solve 'live' issue

Answer (score 0):

put `$(".tools").unbind('click')` before `$(".tools").live("click",function(e){...`
here it is:

```
$(".tools").unbind('click');
$(".tools").live("click",function(e){ ....
//your script here
```